# responsive img with boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a logo in my footer responsive, and it should be centered. I thought I could solve it the following way with bootstrap:

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="landing img-responsive footer">
                <div>
                    <img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.landing.img-responsive.footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But is that incorrect?

Comment: You need to give the image a certain width for it to center this way.

Comment: That div element still takes all of the available width, so the automatic margins on both sides will effectively be 0 – the element _is_ “centered”, but without much of a visible effect. You need to either give the div element a width, or apply auto margin to the image (and make it display:block, because only then those auto margins work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use

```
 <center><img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png" /></center>
```

or alternatively

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="img-responsive">
         <img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png" />
</div>
```

Also  check the space between **.landing .img-responsive .footer** between these **classes in you css.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
img {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

To center the image, while adding the `.img-responsive` class part of bootstrap to make it responsive.

https://jsfiddle.net/c79bstuu/

Answer (score 0):

User img-responsive class for responsive image. 
Use center-block class to horizontallyalign an element center.

```
<img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

it will make your image responsive as well as horizontally center aligned. 
anyhow if you want vertically align then you should use display: table-cell for child div and display:table for parent div. You also need to remove float property from child div.